# Passing a string dynamically to a page using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a registration form with a text field. I am trying to pass the string that is inputted on that field to a php file to validate the string dynamically. What would be the best(performance-wise) way to do it.

using

```
data: { cont: str , inputType : vtype}
```

or a query string

```
url: 'validate.php?q='+str+'t='+vtype;
```

this is my current script:

```
function validate(str,vtype) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'validate.php?q='+str+'t='+vtype,
                timeout: 1000,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#validationIndicator").html(data);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, errorThrown) {
                    $("#validationIndicator").html('');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Although this is largely based on opinion, I would recommend using the former method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, jQuery is meant to make JavaScript development *easier*; why go through string concatenation with more elegant alternatives?

The other thing jQuery does is to make sure your data is properly escaped; to give an example, the equivalent of using `data:` is actually this:

```
url: 'validate.php?q=' + encodeURIComponent(str) + 't=' + encodeURIComponent(vtype);
```

Otherwise, the values of `str` or `vtype` may mess up the query string.

Second, the time spent constructing the request vs the round trip to the server is negligible, so you should pick the option that's simpler and less error prone.

#### Conclusion

Go with this:

```
data: { cont: str , inputType : vtype}
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense, now I have something to explain to my professor. He's really a performance-freak. Always wants an explanation on "why would use this instead of that".

Comment: If that's the case he might ask you why use jQuery instead of Vanilla JS ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I guess I'll check Vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! When you pass `data` key-value pair within `$.ajax({})`, it converts it into a query string, and appends it to `URL`. This is similar to you doing following:

```
url: 'validate.php?q=' + str + '&t=' + vtype;
```

In other words, for `GET` request, it is better to build and use URL (with query string) explicitly, rather than letting jQuery do the conversion for you.

Also, there is a `processData` boolean that you can pass within your `Ajax` request. This boolean, if provided `FALSE`, won't convert `data` to query string automatically.

**Source:** https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for this information :). Surely gonna be helpful when I'm going to explain this to my prof

Comment: No problem. If it helped out, I'd appreciate if you mark it as an answer. Thanks!